# LDAP ADO ADSDSOObject Vs .Net LDAPConnection + SearchRequest Query issue

Tags: .net, ldap, ado

I have a challenge of converting an old VB6 utility to now use .Net.  It is an LDAP import tool.  The old tool uses the ADO ADSDSOObject.   This has some limitations in some circumstances, and we want to replace it.

So, I wrote the new code in .Net, using the LDAPConnection, PageResultRequestControl, and Searchrequest objects.

So far, it works pretty well.  However, with some complex queries that work fine with ADO ADSDSOObject, I'm getting Zero results back (without errors) from the new implementation.

Because LDAP is notorious for reporting errors that are meaningless, I'm having a tough time resolving.

Here's an example of a query that does not return results at all (and no errors) :

```
SELECT
  Samaccountname, sn, givenName, middleName, telephoneNumber, 
  mail, department, title, EmployeeId, description, company 
FROM LDAP://server.tld:389/CN=Users,DC=aaaa,DC=bbbb,DC=cccc,DC=dddd 
WHERE employeeid='*' AND sn='*' AND department='*' 
  AND (extensionAttribute15='page' 
  OR ((company='3*' OR company='6*' OR company='49*' 
  OR company='86065600' OR company='86088900') 
  AND (extensionAttribute15<>'nopage'))
```

Comment: No error means your search filter produced an empty search result, that's all. You should check your filter expression thoroughly.  Also, you are showing your old code accessing AD through its OLE DB provider.

Comment: Here's the rub:  The query produces results using the OLE DB provider.  When I use the same search filter via SearchRequest, it produces no results, which makes no sense to me.